# Can I move the legend outside of the Chart area c# wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, legend

Is there any way to move chart legend out of the Chart area?

If solution exist, i need code behind.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use position property

```
 chart1.Legends[0].Position.Width = 22; // set accordingly 
 chart1.Legends[0].Position.Height = 10;
```